# Grails open empty page without errors

Tags: grails

I feel awkward ask such a trivial question, but I have exhausted all options and Google did not help me. I have following url mappings code:

```
static mappings = {
    "/$controller/$action?/$id?"{
        constraints {
    }
}
"/"(controller:'news', action:'index')
    "500"(view:'/error')
}
```

And controller class:

```
def index() {
    redirect(action: 'result')
}
private doRender(Map params = [:].withDefault { [:] }) {
    def viewPath = "/mobile/news/front/front"

    def completeModel = getDefaultModel() + params.model

    render(view: viewPath,
            model: completeModel)
}
```

GSP page exist and located on following path: `views/mobile/news/front/front.gsp`
After I ran the application, I am trying to open following URL: `http://localhost:8080/` and I'm getting empty page without any errors. I can't figure out what it is, and the complete lack of feedback is killing me. 
Are there logs anywhere I can check? And, is there something obvious I'm missing?

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Is there a "result" action? You just show a private "doRender" method.

Comment: Did you change the context to "/"? The default url is http://localhost:8080/appname/ not http://localhost:8080/

Comment: The redirect() method calls result() method, which in turn calls doRender() method. Yes, I changed the context to the "/".

Comment: You need to show all the code. You should only have forward facing actions in your controllers. Show the result() method.

Comment: Actually, this is all code that I have.

Comment: @AlexKuntsevich If it's all the code, then `redirect(action: 'result')` will produce a 404 error rather than a blank page.

Comment: I apologize for the misunderstanding, here is result method code: `def result() { doRender() }`

Answer (score 0):

The page `http://localhost:8080/` is always empty in Firefox when you run Grails on your machine in the run-app mode. It's not related to url mappings or the like.